# Java: org.codehaus.jackson: How deserialize from string to Enum?

Tags: jackson

I has POJO

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class MyPojo implements Serializable {
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private int id;
    @JsonProperty("type")
    private MyTypeEnum type;
}
```

I deserialize  from string (json) using annotation: **org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty**.
And it's work fine.

But what about Enum? How I can  deserialize from string to enum (e.g. property "**type**") in uppercase?

Here my enum:

```
import org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonProperty;
public enum Type {
@JsonProperty("text")
    TEXT("text"),
    @JsonProperty("external")
    EXTERNAL("external"),
    @JsonProperty("event")
    EVENT("event"),
    @JsonProperty("post")
    POST("post"),
    UNKNOWN("Unknown");

    private String name;

    private Type(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private static Type[] genderList = Type.values();

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
`
```

Error:

```
getLastPromotion: errorMessage: Can not construct instance of com.myproject.Type from String value 'external': value not one of declared Enum instance names
org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of com.bnmt.main.classEnum.PromotionObjectType from String value 'external': value not one of declared Enum instance names
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.StdDeserializationContext.weirdStringException(StdDeserializationContext.java:243)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:80)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.EnumDeserializer.deserialize(EnumDeserializer.java:23)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty.deserialize(SettableBeanProperty.java:299)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.SettableBeanProperty$FieldProperty.deserializeAndSet(SettableBeanProperty.java:579)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserializeFromObject(BeanDeserializer.java:697)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:580)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:104)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.deser.std.ObjectArrayDeserializer.deserialize(ObjectArrayDeserializer.java:18)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:2732)
    at org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:1863)
```

Comment: From what I see the string that comes in the JSON message is 'external', and therefore, not one of the consts in your enum. If you want to deserialize you will need to include 'external' to the enum, or keep using a string.

Comment: It's not help. See code above

Comment: Jackson deserialises a string using the enum's **value**, not **name**. In your code, the value is `"EXTERNAL"` (uppercase, not lowercase). Try deserialising that.

Comment: here working code:
 public enum Type {
    TEXT, EXTERNAL, EVENT, POST, UNKNOWN;

    @JsonCreator
    public static Type fromString(String findName) {
        for (Type type : Type .values()) {
            if (type.name().equalsIgnoreCase(findName)) {
                return type;
            }
        }
        return UNKNOWN;
    }
}